# Как сохранить размер возвращаемого массива, если часть ключей может отсутствовать в таблице

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Например, есть таблица.

```
  -first_table-  
|--var--|-value-|
| int   |   1   |
| float |  1.0  |
| char  |   a   |
|-------|-------|
```

код

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( var text, value text );

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES( 'int', '1' );
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES( 'float', '1.0' );
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES( 'char', 'a' );
```

Генерация запроса:

```
#!/bin/bash
sql=""
table="table1"
for var in float tuple int char bool;do
        sql="${sql}SELECT value FROM '${table}' WHERE var='$var' "
        sql="${sql}UNION ALL "
done
echo -e $sql | sed -e 's/UNION ALL$/;/g'
```

результат:

```
echo "SELECT value FROM 'table1' WHERE var='float' UNION ALL SELECT value FROM 'table1' WHERE var='tuple' UNION ALL SELECT value FROM 'table1' WHERE var='int' UNION ALL SELECT value FROM 'table1' WHERE var='char' UNION ALL SELECT value FROM 'table1' WHERE var='bool' ;" | sqlite3 test.db
```

ответ:

```
1.0
1
a
```

а надо

```
1.0
'N/A'
1
a
'N/A'
```

что бы длина массива запрашиваемого - была равна длине массива в ответе.

Comment: Это же точно то же, что в вашем предыдущем вопросе. Надо что бы в запросе присутствовала выборка, гарантированно дающая все строки и к ней left join уже подклеивать данные

Comment: И вообще не понятно как вы собираетесь этим пользоваться, как вы узнаете какое значение что означает ? ведь SQL не гарантирует порядок записей в выборке в случае если явно не указан order by. Т.е. ваши записи из данного запроса могут вернутся совершенно не в том порядке в каком вы написали union'ы

Comment: у меня в порядке запрашивания выдаётся всегда.

Comment: `Надо что бы в запросе присутствовала выборка,` - нет такой выборки, я могу лишь в запрос подать все имена переменных и хочу получить значения для тех, которые в базе точно есть, одним запросом, что бы не городить кучу SELECT для проверки - есть/нет.

Comment: значит ее надо сделать, вроде `select ... from (select 'float' var,1 num union select 'int',2 union ...) X left join first_table ...` хотя для удобства я бы все таки табличку завел, в которой бы сохранил все известные типы и заодно номера для сортировки, если по алфавиту не подходит. (надо же в запросе будет сортировку какую то указывать, что бы нужные строки на нужных позициях были)

Comment: И да, порядок после union all _обычно_ совпадает, но он все равно не гарантирован и полагаться на это нельзя

Comment: т.е. надо будет делать сортировку и подавать ключи во внутренний select тоже в отсортированном, лексикографическом порядке?

Comment: сортировка делается только снаружи запроса в самом конце. все внутренние сортировки значения не имеют, потому что другие стадии запроса могут переставить записи. если сортировка по названию устаивает просто в самом конце по var сортируйте и все

Comment: Благодарю. Сейчас оформлю самоответ. Получилось.

Comment: немножко бородато получилось (((;

Comment: я вообще то цифры вводил, что бы сортировать по ним, если порядок был бы все таки не по алфавиту. а так они не нужны, поравлю ваш ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря помощи @Mike.

```
select coalesce(F.value, 'N/A') value
  from
   (
        select 'tuple' var  union
        select 'int' union
        select 'float' union
        select 'char' union
        select 'bool'
   ) V
  left join table1 F  on F.var=V.var
 order by V.var desc
```

результат

```
N/A
1
1.0
a
N/A
```

Но внутренний запрос должен быть составлен согласно сортировке `var` по лексикографическому упорядочиванию. Т.к. в данном случае в конце `desc`, то - по убыванию, от `z` к `a`: `tuple`, `int`, `float`, `char`, `bool`.